# Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I'm working on a react native project and any attempt to install packages from `npm` fails with the error below.

```
fitz:tesseractOcrSample fitzmode$ npm i
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/react failed, reason: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/fitzmode/.npm/_logs/2018-09-01T13_08_53_778Z-debug.log
```

Looking at other solutions I have tried to set the `strict-ssl` to `false` in the `npm config` to no avail.

I have also tried using `yarn` instead but get the below.

```
fitz:tesseractOcrSample fitzmode$ yarn install
yarn install v1.7.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.yarnpkg.com registry.yarnpkg.com:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/fitzmode/Downloads/react-native-tesseract-ocr-master/tesseractOcrSample/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

I'm not sure if its a mis-configuration on my network or something else. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Maybe it's related to the [DNS misconfiguration cached in ISP DNS caches](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/v22ffls5cd6h)?

Comment: got the same error while creating docker image

Comment: There seems to have been some outages at npmregistry.org. They corrected them but some ISPs may be caching incorrect DNS config. You can either wait it out or change to OpenDNS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

I have edited my /etc/hosts file and create an entry like this

```
104.16.109.30   registry.npmjs.org
```

and it works.

Comment: Marked this as a better answer than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED

I changed the DNS provider on my machine to `OpenDNS`. Apparently there may have been a misconfiguration on the `npm registry` that may be cached by my ISP.

In `Preferences > Network > Advanced > DNS (Tab)` , I've added 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220 to the list of DNS servers.

More info here [here](https://use.opendns.com/%20%22here:)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Add

```
104.16.16.35    registry.yarnpkg.com
```

to  /etc/hosts